# Razor inside the HTML5

Tags: html, razor

I'm having trouble on putting Razor inside the HTML5.
I can't get the value of **id**.

I placed the Razor inside the body tag.

This is what it looked like:

```
@using ThisIsNamespace
  @{
      VBEncrypt enc = new VBEncrypt();
  if(IsPost)
  {
     if(Request["txtUserID"] != null || Request["txtPassword"] != null)
     {
         Session["USER"] = Request["txtUserID"];
         Session["PASSWORD"] = Request["txtPassword"];
         Session["ID"] = enc.Encrypt("" + Session["USER"] + "]#USERID#[" + Session["Password"] + "");
     }
  }
```

}

and then assign the Session["ID"] to a variable: this is located in the head tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var id = @Session["ID"];
</script>
```

I'm not getting any error but it seems that it fails to assign the session to the variable.
Please let me know if my question is not clear.

Everyones help would be very much appreciated.
Thank you in advance ;)

Comment: When you "View Source" from the web browser, do you see the session id? `var id = xxxxxxx;` ?

Comment: what is written in the HTML is what it also display inside the source : var uid = @Session["ID"]. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simple test:

```
@{
    Session["ID"] = 1;
}
```

Then:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var id = @Session["ID"];
    var id2 = @Session["ID2"];
</script>
```

Renders as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var id = 1;
    var id2 = ;
</script>
```

One of the checks fails. `IsPost` is false OR `Request["txtUserID"]` and `Request["txtPassword"]` are `null`

Comment: Still no luck. nothing is rendered. Am I correct on putting the Razor inside the Body Tag? Thanks.

Comment: @SyntaxError yes, it's correct, what about other code? you could also find it in browser html source?